# Universal Image Loader - Use same image in multiple views

Tags: android, imageview, universal-image-loader

I'm using Universal Image Loader to load images from a backend to display user images in a list; however, if the icon shows up multiple times, the Universal Image Loader doesn't fill out all the views.

- [User Image 1] - No image
- [User Image 1] - No Image
- [User Image 2] - Fine
- [User Image 2] - No Image
- [User Image 3] - Fine
- [User Image 1] - Fine

And then on another screen:

- [User Image 1] - Fine
- [User Image 1] - No image

I'm using cacheInMemory and cacheOnDisk, which seemed to improve it. As before it was only displaying it in one of the views, instead of most, but I need all of them to work.

```
DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheInMemory( true )
            .cacheOnDisk( true )
            .build();

ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder( this )
            .threadPoolSize( 3 )
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions( defaultOptions )
            .build();

ImageLoader.getInstance().init( config );
```

I'm not using a ListView for this task, I'm using a ScrollView and inflating it with a custom layout.

```
private View createSmallActivity( LayoutInflater inflater, final Event activity ) {

    final View view;
    view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.activity_posted_small, null );
    ...
    // The owner's image.
    if( activity.ownerImageUrl != null ) {
        Loader.loadImage( getActivity(),
               activity.ownerImageUrl,
               R.drawable.postedactivitysmall_imageprofileempty,
               ( ImageView ) view.findViewById( R.id.profileImage ) );
    }
    return view;
}



// Loader.loadImage
// Setting the targetSize, and masking the image with a resource.
public static void loadImage( Context context, String url, int resource, ImageView view ) {
    Drawable d = context.getResources().getDrawable( resource );
    int h = d.getIntrinsicHeight();
    int w = d.getIntrinsicWidth();

    ImageSize targetSize = new ImageSize( w, h );
    ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage( url, targetSize, new MaskImageLoader( context, view, resource ) );
}
```

Any idea on how I can improve the Universal Image Loader to ensure all the views are correctly filled out?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you post the code of `getView` function of `Adapter` class where in which you are loading  the image?

Comment: I'm not using an Adapter, I'm using a ScrollView and inflating a layout. I added more details to the question about how I'm loading it. The same problem also happens on another screen where I have to show the same image twice and can't put that in a ScrollView either.

Comment: Could you post your MaskImageLoader code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because Universal Image Loader cancel previous requests with same url (used as id). To prevent this behaviour, replace

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage( url, targetSize, new MaskImageLoader( context, view, resource ) );
```

by

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, 
    new NonViewAware(new ImageSize(w, h), ViewScaleType.CROP),
    new MaskImageLoader(context, view, resource));
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use ListView. Maybe you should declare ImageLoader globally. then use it.

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
...
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView);
```